# Having difficulty with BeautifulSoup scraping USGS streamflow

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

USGS has all sorts of fancy alerts that you can sign up for, but not one that emails you the most recent discharge every morning.  I would like to get that info and practice with BeautifulSoup at the same time.  I have tried so many different Dr. Google methods that my script is more commented-out lines than active ones.  I think I have hit on something with the following:

```
page=requests.get('https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/uv/?site_no=03479000')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
stations=soup.find(class_='stationContainer')
values=stations.find_all('#text')
```

but it isn't actually doing what I need it to do.  Have I used the wrong HTML classes as my search terms?  This is my first time using BeautifulSoup

For reference, I am trying to get the most recent instantaneous discharge value from this site: https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/uv/?site_no=03479000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. This site you are scraping has 3 different `stationContainer` classes, so you need to determine which is the one you want. Then once you get the class you need, you go through all the child tags to find the value you need.

Here is some more documentation on selecting data from BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree

```
page = requests.get('https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/uv/?site_no=03479000')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
stations = soup.select(".stationContainer") #load all tags with the stationContainer tag
dischargeStation = list(stations)[1] #get the second station (discharge)
print(list(dischargeStation.children)[4]) #get the list of children and load the child member that contains your data
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked with a slight modification; I had to change the index in dischargeStation to 2, using 1 pulled up precipitation for some reason.